# Как лучше организовать запуск скрипта парсера, чтобы минимизировать нагрузку на сервер?

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ, парсер, mysql

Здравствуйте! Написал небольшой парсер, всё работает, предварительно залил в БД список адресов карточек товара, т.е. скрипт достаёт из БД например 100 адресов, потом основная часть скрипта (парсер на основе simple_html_dom) ф цикле обрабатывает эти адреса, получает картинку, наименование, цену и свойства товара и вызывает функцию SaveDB которая принимает сформированный массив расталкивает его по БД. Как лучше его запускать? Через php header(...?LIMIT_START=$Limit+100) или писать отдельный скрипт на jquery ajax и перезапускать основной парсер по средствам ajax с интервалов в 500 миллисекунд например? Мне нужно спарсить 36 000 товаров, хочу сделать это с наименьшими нагрузками на сервер.

Comment: А что мешает выполнить данный скрипт без перезапусков? В цикле берите по 100 адресов и парсите на здоровье.

Comment: если нужны минимальные нагрузки на сервер - исключите apache с этого процесса. Запускайте с консоли. Для мускуля возможно ещё транзакции нужно добавить - будет вообще хорошо.

Что бы ещё уменьшить нагрузку на сервер, возможно, нужно будет написать свой парсер html. Вот только времени на это уйдет сколько, что, возможно, дешевле будет прикупить несколько серверов на облачном хостинге и все распарсить (цена вопроса - 5-10 долл в месяц).